# SQL Stored Proc and Dataset

Tags: sql, dataadapter

I've got a sql stored proc that is working fine in SSMS. When I try and execute through code and assign the return to a dataset I am getting zero rows back. I've used the immediate window to ensure that I am sending the correct params to the stored proc and that is all good.

What else would cause me to get zero rows assigned to the dataset. Here is my code.

Thanks,
Mike

EDIT: I'm not getting any exceptions from SQL..

`Public Function GetTransReporting(ByVal transNumber As Long, ByVal customerID As Long) As DataCommon.transReporting`

```
Dim myTransReporting As New transReporting

    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim prm1 As SqlParameter
    Dim prm2 As SqlParameter
    mcmd = New SqlCommand
    mcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    mcmd.Connection = mcn
    mcmd.CommandText = "GetTransReportingByCustomerID"

    prm1 = New SqlParameter("@transNumber", Data.SqlDbType.BigInt)
    prm1.Value = customerID
    mcmd.Parameters.Add(prm1)

    prm2 = New SqlParameter("@customerNumber", Data.SqlDbType.BigInt)
    prm2.Value = transNumber
    mcmd.Parameters.Add(prm2)

    da = New SqlDataAdapter(mcmd)
    da.Fill(myTransReporting)

Return myTransReporting
```

End Function

Comment: What does this stored procedure do? Anything unusual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.. if you take a look at my parameters up top I am accidentally assigning transaction to customer and customer to transaction. DOH!

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Does your stored procedure start  with SET NOCOUNT ON? The lack of this can sometimes cause issues if the stored procedure is processing multiple queries before the final SELECT.